# How to set -private for javadoc in ant build.xml

Tags: java, ant, javadoc

I want to create the javadoc my project with ant, but I don't now how to make it there. In terminal I would execute `javadoc -private ...` but how I have to change mu build.xml to get the same result?

```
<target name="doc" description="generate documentation">                   
    <mkdir dir="${doc}"/>                                                  
    <javadoc sourcepath="${src}" destdir="${doc}"/>                        
</target>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<javadoc sourcepath="${src}" destdir="${doc}" access="private"/>`. Also, consider using an IDE that provides suggestions and autocomplete for things like these.

Comment: thank you very much! I know IDEs are very in favored by a lot of programmers, but I cannot work without vim ;-)